# React native error unsupported file type when start packager

Tags: react-native

I got this issue when deploy react-native app to android simulator(I'm using genymotion).

I deleted and pastes some new png images to the directories under "android\app\src\main\res" then deploy it again but I got the error "unsupported file type". I tried to restart the packager, delete all images under those directories, closed everything and opened again, even I tried to restart my PC but still get this error.

[image: This is the error image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to fix it:
I tried the following ways and it's working: 
1. Close all terminal windows, delete your node_modules folder, run npm cache clean and npm install
2. run this command : **react-native start --assetRoots ./android/app/src/main/res/**